# How to combine both correction for restriction of range and attenuation?

Tags: correlation, scales

I have two measurements obtained by two different scales that I want to correlate. Because of the nature of the sample I should use both a correction for attenuation and a correction of restriction of range. My first thought was to do a correction of restriction of range before I do a correction for attenuation. Is it as simple as that? Is this a logical way of thinking or should I somehow account for the fact that I *correct* a *corrected* correlation? Somehow it feels like doing partially a double job.